# Right Noetherian but not Right Artinian

Tags: ring-theory

I am searching for examples of rings which is Right Noetherian but not Right Artinian.
I tried experimenting on matrix rings but no success.
Just wanted to know if such an example is possible or not.

If yes then hint should suffice else which theorem can I use to prove it

Comment: I'd say start simple--what's your favorite non-field Noetherian ring?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is the one

Comment: Here’s the [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=64l&L=63l) for that.

Comment: @permutation_matrix Is $\mathbb{Z}$ Artinian?